# How do I add a icons (like search, heart, options) to the top of my android cardviews, like in image?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-activity

I've wrote a small application, which shows several android cards each with coloured headers.

I'd like to be able to *add icons to the top right of each card*, like in the image belo So far although I've found screenshots like the below suggesting that it is possible. I haven't found any information online how to do this. So some help would be fantastic :-)

[image]

My code so far is below:

**CardAdapter.java**

```
public class CardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public List<TTItem> posts = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItems(List<TTItem> items) {
        posts.addAll(items);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void clear() {
        posts.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_cardview, null);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(posts.get(position).title);
        Picasso.with(holder.mImageView.getContext()).load(posts.get(position).images[0]).into(holder.mImageView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return posts.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView mTextView;
        public ImageView mImageView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
            mImageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
    @InjectView(R.id.mainView)
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    @InjectView(R.id.refreshContainer)
    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private CardAdapter mAdapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
        int actionBarHeight = 0;
        if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
            actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
        refreshLayout.setProgressViewEndTarget(true, actionBarHeight);
        mAdapter = new CardAdapter();
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 1);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        mAdapter.clear();
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 2500);
    }
}
```

**Activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">



    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/refreshContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/mainView"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

**item_cardview.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout     <!-- This is the specific part you asked to color -->
            android:id="@+id/heading_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/teal_500"
            android:padding="36dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_heading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="22 mins to Ancona"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="36sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_subheading"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tv_heading"
                android:text="Light traffic on ss16"
                android:textColor="@color/teal_200"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="Assigned delivery boy"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_map" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_footer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tv_heading"
            android:text="It is just an example!"
            android:textColor="@color/grey_500"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to add the icons in the card not in the toolbar of the actibity, right? 
Then add a relativelayout which align on top of your card. You can add the icons into this layout and let them align right. 
The main content of your card should align below the relativelayout. Voila :)